# Calculate how the solution of the following system of differential equations behave in infinity.

Tags: infinity, differential

The system is given by

$u_i'=-\lambda (u_i-u_{i-1}) - \lambda (u_i - u_{i+1})$

The inital conditions are given by $u_1(0)=u_1^0 \geq 0,..., u_n(0)=u_N^0\geq 0$.

We need to prove that

$\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty}u_i(t) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}u_i(0), \quad i=0,...,N-1$

Comment: How do $u_1$ and $u_N$ behave at later times? (Given what you have to prove I actually do know the answer but I want you to figure it out or at least notice it if it was given.)

Comment: Knowing the answer, it is clear that each of the variables will be finally compensated. I mean that if one variable is possitive from the beginning, as they are because of the hypothesis, it will increase if it values is less than the average or decrease if the value is higher. Maybe not from the beginning, but it will from a certain t*.

Comment: There is a natural way for this to happen through a discrete version of homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions, since this is itself a discretization of the heat equation.

Comment: yes it is, but I don't know hot to prove the result

Comment: Perform a spectral analysis, check that the eigenvector with eigenvalue 0 is constant and all the other eigenvalues are strictly negative.

Comment: Note that the easy way to do this is to note that the matrix is symmetric with negative diagonal entries and then use Gerschgorin's theorem. This tells you the eigenvalues are all nonpositive; then you can check that the only eigenvector with eigenvalue zero is the constant one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written the system is not closed: $u_1'$ and $u_N'$ cannot be specified this way since there is no $u_0$ or $u_{N+1}$ to use to define the second derivative. However, one can examine $\sum_{i=2}^{N-1} u_i'=\lambda \sum_{i=1}^{N-2} u_i - 2 \lambda \sum_{i=2}^{N-1} u_i + \lambda \sum_{i=3}^N u_i=\lambda u_1-\lambda u_2 + \lambda u_N - \lambda u_{N-1}$. To get the desired limiting behavior, one must then have that $u_1'+\lambda u_1 - \lambda u_2 + u_N' + \lambda u_N - \lambda u_{N-1}$ integrates out to zero in time. The standard way to achieve that is the Neumann boundary condition $u_1'=-\lambda u_1 + \lambda u_2,u_N'=-\lambda u_N + \lambda u_{N-1}$.

Once you have specified that boundary condition, one can form the associated system matrix and apply the Gerschgorin circle theorem and the symmetry to conclude that the eigenvalues are real and nonpositive. Thus the only thing that matters for the qualitative long term behavior is the eigenvector(s) with eigenvalue zero. Determine those (it will turn out that there is just one). Then exploit the symmetry to determine the coefficient of that eigenvector in the eigenbasis expansion of the initial condition (without having to compute all the other coefficients in the eigenbasis expansion). Then you're basically done.